# Random characters when reading from pipe

Tags: c++, operating-system, fork, ipc, pipe

In the following code :

```
    ...
    char *message = "This is the message!";
    ...

    printf("Writing to file descriptor FD[%i] \n", fd[1]);
    write( fd[1], message, strlen(message));
    printf("Reading from file descriptor FD[%i] \n", fd[0]);
    read( fd[0], buffer, strlen(message));
    printf("Message from FD[%i] : \"%s\" .\n", fd[0], buffer);
```

I get the following output :

```
 "This is the message!���" .
```

But if I remove the "!" from my message, the output doesn't have random characters... Any idea why I get these 3 random characters to appear?

Comment: Always use a `const char *` when pointing to constant characters.

Comment: You're not making use of the return value from `read`. Doing so would give you a hint...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write your message of length `strlen(whatever)`, that does *not* include the terminating NUL character. Hence what comes out at the other end is *not* a C string but rather just a collection of characters.

What *follows* that collection of characters in memory depends entirely upon what was there before you read them from the pipe. Since it's not a C string (except by possible accident if the memory location following just happened to *already* contain a NUL), you should not be passing it to `printf` with an unbounded `%s` format specifier.

You have two possibilities here. The first is to send the NUL character along with the data with something like:

```
write (fd[1], message, strlen(message) + 1);
```

or (probably better) use the return value from `read` which tells you how many bytes were read, something like:

```
int sz = read (fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
// should probably check sz here as well.
printf ("Message from FD[%i] : \"%*s\" .\n", fd[0], sz, buffer);
```

Comment: @Erwald, yes. Although it's unusual to use pipes in this sort of situation, where you know the length at the receiving end _before_ you read the data. Normally, you would impose your own protocol, such as reading single characters until you get the NUL.